# What is diffrence between odbc_connect() and mssql_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server

In php, to connect to MSSQL server , what is diffrence between odb_connect() and mssql_connect()???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`odbc_connect()` requires you have the PHP ODBC extension loaded and UNIXodbc installed and configured on the web server, whereas `mssql_connect()` only requires that you have the MSSQL extension.

Answer (score 3):

odbc_connect is a generic database connection (you can specify the driver), while mssql_connect is MSSQL specific

Also the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) says that complex queries may fail with odbc drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to connect to a SQL Server via PHP, might I recommend that you use Microsoft's SQLSRV PHP driver. It's much better than the native php_mssql extension and gives you a lot more functionality. Make sure you also install SQL Server native client, or it won't work.